# HTML5 canvas : counterclockwise arc with angle > 2 PI

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I try to figure why angle > 2 PI does not give the same result when drawing an arc clockwise and counterclockwise.

Look at this code snippet, on the first line I draw "clockwise" 3 red arcs with a start angle of 0 and an end angle of PI, 2*PI and 3*PI.
Then I draw "counterclockwise" 3 blue arcs with same parameters.

The 3rd result bewilders me... Can anyone explain this to me ?

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

// CLOCKWISE, angle = PI
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(50, 50, 40, 0, Math.PI, false);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.stroke();
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.fill();

// CLOCKWISE, angle = 2 PI
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(150, 50, 40, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.stroke();
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.fill();

// CLOCKWISE, angle = 3 PI
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(250, 50, 40, 0, 3 * Math.PI, false);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.stroke();
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.fill();

// COUNTERCLOCKWISE, angle = PI
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(50, 150, 40, 0, Math.PI, true);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.stroke();
ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
ctx.fill();

// COUNTERCLOCKWISE, angle = 2 PI
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(150, 150, 40, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.stroke();
ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
ctx.fill();

// COUNTERCLOCKWISE, angle = 3 PI
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(250, 150, 40, 0, 3 * Math.PI, true);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.stroke();
ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
ctx.fill();
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="350" height="250" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According [to specs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/canvas.html#ellipse-method-steps):

> If *anticlockwise* is false and *endAngle-startAngle* is equal to or greater than 2π, or, if *anticlockwise* is true and *startAngle-endAngle* is equal to or greater than 2π, then the arc is the whole circumference of this ellipse, and the point at *startAngle* along this circle's circumference, measured in radians clockwise from the ellipse's semi-major axis, acts as both the start point and the end point.
>
> Otherwise, the points at *startAngle* and *endAngle* along this circle's circumference, measured in radians clockwise from the ellipse's *semi-major axis*, are the start and end points respectively, and the arc is the path along the circumference of this ellipse from the start point to the end point, going anti-clockwise if anticlockwise is true, and clockwise otherwise. Since the points are on the ellipse, as opposed to being simply angles from zero, the arc can never cover an angle greater than 2π radians.

Put in maybe clearer pseudo-code:

```
if(
  (anticlockwise === false && (endAngle - startAngle) >= 2π) ||
  (anticlockwise === true  && (startAngle - endAngle) >= 2π)
  ) {
  arc_circumference = 2π;
}
else {
  startAngle = startAngle % 2π;
  endAngle = endAngle % 2π;
}
```

In your case, *startAngle = 0*, *endAngle = 3π*, *anticlowkwise = true*, if we run the above algorithm, we end up in the else case *(0 - 3π < 2π)* and *endAngle* is now *(3π % 2π = 1π)*.

We could achieve the same output without the anticlockwise flag by swapping *startAngle* and *endAngle*:

```js
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
// COUNTERCLOCKWISE, angle = -3 PI (from OP)
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(50, 150, 40, 0, 3 * Math.PI, true);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
ctx.fill();

// CLOCKWISE, angle = -3 PI
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(50, 50, 40, 3 * Math.PI, 0);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.fill();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you go COUNTERCLOCKWISE, after 0 comes 2PI. You should try this instead:

```js
// COUNTERCLOCKWISE, angle = 3 PI
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(250, 150, 40, 2 * Math.PI, 0, true);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.stroke();
ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
ctx.fill();
```

UPDATE:

After OP's comment I've added an animated demo:

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
let delta = 0;

function Draw(){
 requestAnimationFrame(Draw) 
 delta+= .01; 
ctx.clearRect(0,0,c.width,c.height)

// CLOCKWISE: animating the end point
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(50, 50, 40, 0, delta, false);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.stroke();


// CONTERCLOCKWISE, animating the start point
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(150, 50, 40, 0,-delta, true);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.stroke();

}

Draw()
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="350" height="250" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"/>
```

Comment: If I understand your answer correctly, it's like in COUNTERCLOCKWISE all angles are like modulo(2*PI) but not in CLOCKWISE... 
So I should go for _end to start in clockwise order_ instead of going for _start to end in counterclockwise order_ to avoid this behavior.
But is this behavior the expected one for path, or a side effect ?

Comment: I think you are wright. I've added an animated demo that show what happens. Please take a look.

Comment: @enxaneta you seem to not get yourself perfectly what happens... Have a look at my answer: what matters is the difference between start and end angles or the inverse. So if an animation makes things clearer to you, https://jsfiddle.net/qL0tdj7a/. There you'll see that values are indeed *modulated*.